# Rendering partial for table row with form_tag is getting crazy!

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have 23(column)x6(row) table and change the row with link_to_remote function.
each *tr tag* has its own *id attribute*.

*change* link call *change action* and change action changes the row using render function wit partial.

_change.html.erb

```
<td id="row_1">1</td>
.
.
omitted
.
.
<td id="row_23">23</td>
```

link_to_remote function

```
<%= link_to_remote 'Change', :update => 'row_1', :url => change_path %>
```

change action

```
def change
  logger.debug render :partial => 'change'
end
```

If I coded like above, everything work okay. This means all changed-columns are in *one row*.

But, if I wrap partial code with *form_for* function like below...

```
<% form_for 'change' do %>
<td id="row_1">1</td>
.
.
omitted
.
.
<td id="row_23">23</td>
<% end %>
```

Then, one column located in one row and that column is the first column. I've looked up the log file, but it was normal html tags.

What's wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the HTML that's being generated. It's not valid to have `td` elements wrapped by `form` elements. Table cells have to be within table rows.

Comment: then, are there any way to make editable row in table? that code worked normally if not a ajax style form.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use  [remote_form_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#M002178) for the ajax form

```
<% remote_form_for 'change' do %>
```

instead of

```
<% form_for 'change' do %>
```

Comment: It does not work. here's screen capture of wrong result. http://www.flickr.com/photos/38742438@N05/4710821079/

Comment: It works find with IE8, and cause wrong result with Chrome. What's the problem?